# What's the url for signing process?

Tags: install4j

From time to time we have problems with the signing process of install4j and it seems to be a problem with the connection to the signing service. Related tpo the thread *[SocketTimeoutException during signing process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680587/sockettimeoutexception-during-signing-process)* we increased the timeout to 60 seconds. However we got still the problem with the connection and now we will check the infrastructer of our build environment. Furthermore we want to install a connection check for the signing url. Therefore we need the url that is used to sign up the executables. Is the following one the right one:  *http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll*? It was logged by install4j during an error build run.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll` is the URL that is used to generate the timestamp signature.

You can change that URL by setting the VM parameter `-Dinstall4j.timestampUrl=[url]`. See [Alternative timestamping services for Authenticode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872105/alternative-timestamping-services-for-authenticode) for alternative URLs.

Comment: Does the URL changed since install4j version 6.0.4? Since we updated to 6.1.3 and the maven plugin with version 1.1.1 our automatic build process is broken and the log entry points to another resource:

_install4j: compilation failed. Reason: error during counter signing: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://timestamp.globalsign.com_

Comment: No, it has remained the same. It is probably a temporary outage or a network problem.

Comment: Wireshark show different http URLs.  install4j 6.0.4 with maven.plugiin 1.0. use [http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll](http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll) and Install4j 6.1.3 wih maven plugin 1.1.1 use [http://timestamp.globalsign.com](http://timestamp.globalsign.com/)

Comment: Sorry about that, I was not looking back far enough. You can set the timestamp URL by defining the compiler variable `sys.ext.timestampUrl` in your project. Although the current URL works for me.